# How to render an AngularJS template to a String without causing InProg error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to write a service which renders a given template and scope to a string.

This is the code:

```
utilModule.factory('CompilerService', ['$compile', '$templateCache',
    function ($compile, $templateCache) {
        return {
            renderTemplateToString: function(templateName, scope) {
                var template = $templateCache.get(templateName);
                var linkFn = $compile(template);
                var linkedContent = linkFn(scope);
                scope.$apply();

                return linkedContent.html();
            }
        }
    }]);
```

When I call this however, I am getting the angular InProg err, caused by the call to $apply():

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

I am calling $apply() in order for the variables to be substituted within the template before retrieving the html.

Any ideas on how to achieve this without the InProg error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

```
if ( !scope.$$phase )
    scope.$apply();
```

this is checking if the code is being executed during a $digest cycle.

However, `$timeout` is preferred:

```
$timeout( function(){
  var template = $templateCache.get(templateName);
                var linkFn = $compile(template);
                var linkedContent = linkFn(scope);
}, 0)
```

**EDIT**: in order to use premises, you should do something like that:

```
    renderTemplateToString: function(templateName, scope) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function(){
               var template = $templateCache.get(templateName);
               var linkFn = $compile(template);
               var linkedContent = linkFn(scope);
               scope.$apply();
               deferred.resolve( linkedContent.html() );
            }, 0);

            return deferred.promise;
    }
```

$timeout is waiting to the `$digest` to finish before executing

Comment: Ideally I wanted to return a String from this service, so if I used the timeout, would I then need to return a promise which is passed the rendered template?